# Angular wrong css order in production build

Tags: angular

I have two css files which I load them in src/assets as following:

My `Angular.json` file:

```
"styles": [
  "src/assets/css/base.css",
  "src/assets/css/template.css"
]
```

I have a class which I defined in both files.

In **base.css** I have the following:

```
.my-class {
  background: red;
}
```

And In **template.css** I have the following:

```
.my-class {
  background: blue;
}
```

When I serve the app with `ng serve` I see **blue** background (red background is going to be overwritten by the blue background and it's the true scenario).

But when I build the project by `ng build --prod` it gives me the wrong order. This means I see the **red** background. Any idea?

Comment: Yeah, had the same issue. The normal production build messes up the css order. Answer below works. Very annoying issue.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known (and open) issue with angular:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9475

A possible workaround:

```
ng build --prod -extract-css false
```

Alternatively you could just try to be more precise with your css selectors

Comment: I think more important than the cli version is @angular-devkit/build-angular which organises the build scripts, but I could be wrong

Comment: Ran into this a few months ago, still not fixed as it seems. The normal production build messes up the order of css sheets indeed.

Comment: I also saw some people talk about just loading one css file and dynamic importing all node modules css from it, but I haven't managed to get it working successfully myself

Comment: Well that seems like even more work and to be honest not worth the time. That is basically how the CLI would do it right? One big CSS file, if it only did it in the specified order haha

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the case every time but one weird behavior is that if you have @import in your css it creates a new file at the bottom of the generated css file, which causes things to get out-of-order (source https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9475#issuecomment-427225617)

> The problem is with your @import like you are importing some google
> font. So Angular transpile that stylesheet on priority basis and gets
> loaded before the said order. Let see this example:
>
> "styles": ["node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
> "src/assets/css/new-age.css" ],
>
> Just look at this new-age.css file: @import
> url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Oswald'); html, body
> { width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #edf1f5; } ......
>
> Solution is to make a separate css file for these imports and then
> mention it angular.json like this:
>
> "styles": ["node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
> "src/assets/css/new-age.css", "src/assets/css/imp.css" ],

My suggestions is to either avoid using @import completely (you can use a link tag from the index.html instead) or use @import for all the styles (so that the list on angular.json only has styles.css)